# How can I hide an actionbutton in Shiny using Javascript

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I am quite a rookie when it comes to shiny.
Here in my app I require to hide a button when I click it, and here I am bringing in JS to get that effect, but I am unable to get it as the buttons don't show up when I run the app.

the following is the code I use.

## ui.R

```
shinyUI( fluidPage(

titlePanel("Conditional panels"),

column(3, wellPanel(
a<-actionButton("action", label="Action"),
br(),
br()
)),

column(4,
     "This will show the button",
     "when we click action.",
     
     conditionalPanel("input.action > 0",
                      a1<- actionButton("show1", label="Show_1"), a2<-actionButton("show2", label="Show_2"), tags$script('document.getElementById("action").style.visibility="hidden";'))
)
))
```

It is a bit confusing.
Are there any method other than conditionalPanel which I can explore?
Do I also need an extra configuration in server.R

Kindly Help.

Comment: Well, right now you just hide it. But you say you want to hide it when it's clicked. So add an IF statement to javascript.

Comment: I tried but It won't read the If statement and the out put remains the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add some javascript that will hide the button when you click on it.

Leaving the rest of your UI the same, you could use:

```
column(3, wellPanel(
    a<-actionButton("action", label="Action"),
    tags$script(HTML('document.getElementById("action").onclick = function(){$(this).hide() }')),
    br(),
    br()  
  ))
```

The jQuery function `hide` will be called on the button once it is clicked on.